# Understanding the rewritten form of Nesterov Accelerated Gradient used to derive Nadam

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

[This](https://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2015/054_report.pdf), other papers and [this blog](https://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/) suggest that we can rewrite the NAG algorithm which basically does
$$\theta _{t+1\:}=\theta _t\:-m_t$$
with $$m_t=\gamma \:m_{t-1}+\eta \frac{\partial L(\theta _t-\gamma \:m_{t-1})}{\partial\theta_t}$$

as
$$\theta _{t+1\:}=\theta _t\:-\left(\gamma m_t\:+\eta \:\frac{\partial L\left(\theta _t\right)}{\partial \theta_t}\right)$$
with $$m_t=\gamma \:m_{t-1}+\eta \frac{\partial L(\theta _t)}{\partial\theta_t}$$
Plugging, they clearly are not the same iterative scheme. Rather, the "rewritten NAG" seems as if its just the classic SGD with momentum but with different weights for $m_{t-1}$ and $\frac{\partial L(\theta _t)}{\partial\theta_t}$. Is there any proof that these two are the same or at least do the same thing? Is there any intuition why would they be?

Thank you.

Comment: Meaning of "Nadam" ?

Comment: It's an optimization algorithm built on top of Adam. Check the first link for more.

Comment: Please provide full references.  Eventually, all links will be broken.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any proof that these two are the same or at least do the same thing?

Answer : YES, these two formulas are equilavent (proof below).

> Rather, the "rewritten NAG" seems as if its just the classic SGD with momentum but with different weights.

Answer : NO, Nesterov is not equivalent to classic momentum with different weight.

**Proof :** Nesterov formula (as it was originaly written by the author) involes **two sequences** of parameters $(x_t)_{t=0..T}$, $(y_t)_{t=0..T}$, which are closed to each other (meaning $\|x_t-y_t\|$ goes to zero). Note : I denote the parameters $x_t$ and $y_t$ instead of $\theta_t$).
Nesterov update is the following :
$$ \begin{cases}
(1) \quad x_{t} & = y_t - \eta \cdot L'(y_t) \\
(2) \quad m_t & = x_{t} - x_{t-1} \\
(3) \quad y_{t+1} & = x_{t} + \gamma \cdot m_t \\
\end{cases}$$
You can rewrite (3) :
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
y_{t+1}
&=& (y_t - \eta \cdot L'(y_t)) + \gamma m_t \\
&=& y_t + \gamma m_t - \eta \cdot L'(y_t)
\end{eqnarray*}$$
And you can find an update formula for $m_t$, because
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
m_{t+1} 
&=& x_{t+1} - x_{t} \\
&=& y_{t+1} - \eta \cdot L'(y_{t+1}) - x_t \\
&=& (x_t + \gamma \cdot m_t) - \eta \cdot L'(y_{t+1}) - x_t \\
&=& \gamma \cdot m_t - \eta \cdot L'(y_{t+1}) \\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

So discarding the sequence $(x_t)_t$, **Nesterov is equivalent to** :
$$ \begin{cases}
m_t & = \gamma \cdot m_{t-1} - \eta \cdot L'(y_t) \\
y_{t+1} & = t_{t} + \gamma \cdot m_t - \eta \cdot L'(y_t) \\
\end{cases}$$

**On the other hand**, instead of discarding $(x_t)_t$, you can discard $(y_t)_t$, and I let you show that, **Nesterov is equivalent to** :
$$ \begin{cases}
m_{t+1} & = \gamma \cdot m_t - \eta \cdot L'(x_t + \gamma \cdot m_t ) \\
x_{t} & = x_{t-1} + m_t\\
\end{cases}$$

So in fact, strictly speaking, both updates are not the same because one is the update on $x_t$ and the other is an update on $y_t$, but **both sequences are binded** in Nesterov's scheme.

Concerning the difference with Momentum, I have recently answered the question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179915.

Comment: Do you think you know why would anyone want to add z to the mix, as in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.02167.pdf#appendix.C?